# MySQL ranking in presence of indexes using variables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Using the classic trick of using @N=@N + 1 to get the rank of items on some ordered column. Now before ordering I need to filter out some values from the base table by inner joining it with some other table. So the query looks like this -:

```
SET @N=0;
SELECT 
  @N := @N + 1 AS rank,
  fa.id,
  fa.val 
FROM
    table1 AS fa 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS em 
      ON em.id = fa.id 
      AND em.type = "A" 
ORDER BY fa.val ;
```

The issue is if I don't have an index on the em.type, then everything works fine but if I put an index on em.type then hell unleashes and the rank values instead of coming ordered by the val column comes in the order the rows are stored in the em table.

here are sample outputs -:

without index-:

```
rank    id         val
1   05F8C7  55050.000000
2   05HJDG  51404.733458
3   05TK1Z  46972.008208
4   05F2TR  46900.000000
5   05F349  44433.412847
6   06C2BT  43750.000000
7   0012X3  42000.000000
8   05MMPK  39430.399658
9   05MLW5  39054.046383
10  062D20  35550.000000
```

with index-:

```
rank      id        val
480     05F8C7  55050.000000
629     05HJDG  51404.733458
1603    05TK1Z  46972.008208
466     05F2TR  46900.000000
467     05F349  44433.412847
3534    06C2BT  43750.000000
15      0012X3  42000.000000
1109    05MMPK  39430.399658
1087    05MLW5  39054.046383
2544    062D20  35550.000000
```

I believe the use of indexes should be completely transparent and outputs should not be effected by it. Is this a bug in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This "trick" was a bomb waiting to explode. A clever optimizer will evaluate a query as it sees fits, optimizing for speed - that's why it's called optimizer. I don't think this use of MySQL variables was documented to work as you expect it to work, but it was working.

Was working, up until recent improvements on the MariaDB optimizer. It will probably break as well in the mainstream MySQL as there are several improvements on the optimizer in the (yet to be released, still beta) 5.6 version.

What you can do (until MySQL implemented window functions) is to use a self-join and a grouping. Results will be consistent, no matter what future improvements are done in the optimizer. Downside is that that it may not be very efficient:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS rank,
  fa.id,
  fa.val 
FROM
    table1 AS fa 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS em 
      ON em.id = fa.id 
      AND em.type = 'A'

    INNER JOIN

    table1 AS fa2 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS em2 
      ON em2.id = fa2.id 
      AND em2.type = 'A' 

      ON fa2.id <= fa.id 
                          --- assuming that `id` is the Primary Key of the table
GROUP BY fa.id
ORDER BY fa.val ;
```